# Automation of Snowflake marketplace data without UI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We want to Integrate Snowflake marketplace data into Snowflake database. I moved the data from UI but, Is there any possibility to automate this process to connect any marketplace data by changing a connector.

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by “changing a connector”? Can you update your question with more detail about the type of solution you are looking for? What toolset are you expecting to use to automate this: SnowSQL, Python, stream lit, etc?

Comment: Marketplace data means its not a single source right, I may take any company data, I dont want to get the data every time manually from UI. Need to switch different marketplace source depends on the need. Hope you understand. It can be a SnowSQL or python anything is fine for me. Need a thought how we can automate this.

Comment: Please say a little more. What do you mean by "get the data every time manually"?

Answer (score 0):

As things are, an ACCOUNTADMIN would need to add a marketplace listing only once per account, and then it will be available for everyone on the account with the roles that the ACCOUNTADMIN chooses can see the imported database.

See step 5 and 6 on https://other-docs.snowflake.com/en/collaboration/consumer-listings-access.html#accessing-listings-on-the-marketplace:

- (Optional) Specify a database name for the data in the listing.
- (Optional) Add roles to grant access to the database created from the listing.

Once it's been added, anyone with the correct role can use the full qualified name of a table in a way similar to:

```sql
select *
from "chosen_database_name"."provider_schema"."provider_table"
```